# CRM 2011 - Updating an entity attribute using javascript without saving the entire entity

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

In my CRM 2011, I have an entity named Phone Call.

This Phone Call entity has a button which sends a request to an external API. This button can be pressed only once for an entity record.

I want that after this button is pressed, I also save to CRM, the time this button was pressed. However, at the same time, the entity will be in edit mode and the user might be in middle of his edit.

So, I do not want the entire entity to be saved. The entire entity will be saved when the user presses the "Save" button.

How can i save just an attribute without waiting for "Save" button press ?

Comment: Adding code to your question always greatly improves the chance of getting an answer and no downvotes. Always remember that when asking!

Answer (score 1):

The only other option would be to [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607664.aspx#bkmk_updateSingleProperty) the record using JavaScript. Also remember to set the attribute value on the form with the same value in case the user ends up saving the record after the fact. This will prevent overwriting the attribute value with a user save.

E.g. to update the phone number attribute on a phone call entity.

```
PATCH [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/phonecalls(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)/phonenumber HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0

{"value": "123-456-7890"}
```

Comment: replace 'PUT' with 'PATCH '. PUT will try to replace the entier entity while PATCH is used for partial update

Comment: the way i did is by creating an entity record using javascript.. to this entity record, i am passing a guid value (of my actual target entity record) and the value of the attribute i want to set.. there is a plugin written on PreSave of this entity..this plugin reads the input guid and it's value and from C# code, i make update to the target entity